# wrapped v-text-field causes warnings and doesn't refresh data

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I'm new to vue.js and I'm trying to make a form, using Vue, vuetify, and vuelidate. If I don't wrap the v-text-field : no problem. If I wrap it in components : problem.
The value is not updated, and there is a warning "[Vue warn] Set operation on key "model" failed: target is readonly. "

You can see what's happening on this sandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-newton-dx9p4s?file=/src/components/Form.vue

And see the code (that I'm focusing on) here :

Form.vue :

```
<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue";
import { useVuelidate } from "@vuelidate/core";
import { required } from "@vuelidate/validators";
import StyledInput from "./StyledInput.vue";
import StyledInput2 from "./StyledInput2.vue";
import StyledInput3 from "./StyledInput3.vue";

const formData = reactive({
  username: "",
  username2: "",
  username3: "",
  username4: "",
});

const rules = {
  username: { required },
  username2: { required },
  username3: { required },
  username4: { required },
};

const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, formData);
</script>

<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="formData.username"
    label="Username 1"
    @input="v$.username.$touch;"
    @blur="v$.username.$touch"
    variant="outlined"
  ></v-text-field>
  <div>{{ formData.username }}</div>
  <StyledInput
    :model="formData.username2"
    label="Username 2"
    :fieldData="v$.username2"
  />
  <div>{{ formData.username2 }}</div>
  <StyledInput2
    :model="formData.username3"
    label="Username 3"
    :fieldData="v$.username3"
  />
  <div>{{ formData.username3 }}</div>
  <StyledInput3
    v-model="formData.username4"
    label="Username 4"
    :fieldData="v$.username4"
  />
  <div>{{ formData.username4 }}</div>
</template>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

MyInput.vue :

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  model: {
    //type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  fieldData: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="props.model"
    :label="props.label"
    :error-messages="props.fieldData.$errors.map((e) => e.$message)"
    @input="props.fieldData.$touch;"
    @blur="props.fieldData.$touch"
    variant="outlined"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<style></style>
```

StyledInput.vue:

```
<script setup>
import MyInput from "./MyInput.vue";

const props = defineProps({
  model: {
    //type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  fieldData: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <MyInput v-bind="props"></MyInput>
</template>

<style></style>
```

I provided more different attempts on the sandbox.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, any idea?

Thank you

Comment: `v-model="props.model"` this is the problem.  Props should be immutable, and v-model is going to attempt to set a new value on props.model.  Props should be used as [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow): "when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent's state" ... "In most cases, the child should emit an event to let the parent perform the mutation"

Comment: @yoduh I tried to do what you said, it didn't work. Could you provide an example? Maybe with a fork of the provided codesandbox?

Comment: Sure thing. I've posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Vue warn] Set operation on key "model" failed: target is readonly.

This warning comes from mutating a prop, which is happening here on the v-text-field:

```js
<v-text-field
  v-model="props.model"
  ...
></v-text-field>
```

Props should be treated as readonly because they represent [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow). To get around this limitation, desired mutations can be emitted to the parent which can safely perform the mutation on the original object. This can pair nicely with using [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model) because the custom child component receiving a v-model receives it as a prop and emits the changes to the parent.

The given codesandbox is not the most simple example to work with because the prop goes two child components deep, but it can be done. I would set v-model on StyledInput:

**Form.vue**

```html
<StyledInput
    v-model="formData.username2"
    label="Username 2"
    :fieldData="v$.username2"
  />
```

In the first child component, define the v-model prop `modelValue`, then continue passing props to the next child and set up the emit:

**StyledInput.vue**

```js
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    //type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})
```

```html
<MyInput
  v-bind="props"
  @update:modelValue="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"
></MyInput>
```

Then basically repeat the same thing in the next child component, but now also setting the `value` prop of the v-text-field and emit changes based on the `input` event:

**MyInput.vue**

```js
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    //type: String,
    required: true,
  },
```

```html
<v-text-field
  :value="props.modelValue"
  @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
></v-text-field>
```

`:value="props.modelValue"` is a one-way binding. v-text-field will display the value of `props.modelValue` but not overwrite it. When a user inputs a new value, the event with new value is emitted up all the way to Form.vue where the actual mutation is made (the v-model). Once the new value is set, it flows back down to be redisplayed in v-text-field's `:value`. It all happens so fast as to appear seamless.

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-stallman-o75i7n?file=/src/components/Form.vue)

Finally, just as a tip, if passing data between multiple levels of components feel too messy or too difficult to maintain, consider using a global store like [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have questions though:
1) you're emitting an "update:modelValue" event, not an "input" event. is it for a reason?
2) In MyInput.vue, you're giving as an event parameter the value ($event.target.value), but in StyledInput, you give an $event object. Why?
3) In Form.vue, I don't see any @update:modelValue on the <StyledInput>. So you're not doing anything with the transmitted event. And yet it works. How so?

Comment: 1) v-model expects an event `update:modelValue`, the MyInput.vue component could re-emit `input` instead as long as StyledInput.vue still emits `update:modelValue` then it'd be fine. 2) `$event.target.value` is what I'm catching from the input event of v-text-field and I re-emit that primitive value by itself so the next component up will only need to catch `$event`.  3) I don't need to manually catch anything in Form.vue because it's already baked into `v-model`, as the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) state v-model under the hood expands to a prop + event listener

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in StyledInput, $event isn't actualy an event. It's just a string. Okay, everything is clear. Thanks a lot for everything.